# Camunda:How to import json file data to embeded form?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, camunda, camunda-modeler

I have json file in which i pernamently rewrite data from my database ,so inside it i have several json object ( i mean i have json array inside my json File) i want to make one form for one json object for this reason i have used embedde forms i mean user task form and angular ui , here is my code:
v

```
ar jsonFile;
inject([ ‘$scope’, ‘$http’, ‘$location’, ‘Uri’, function($scope, $http, $location, Uri) {

    camForm.on('form-loaded', function () {
        $http.get(Uri.appUri("engine://engine/:engine/process-definition/key/my-process-key/startForm")).success(function(result){
            var contextPath = result.contextPath + '/forms/';       
            var filePath = contextPath + 'data.json';
            $.getJSON(filePath, function(json) {
                jsonFile = json;
            });
        }); 
    });
   var jsonData1=JSON.stringify(jsonFile); 
   var rawData=JSON.parse(jsonData1);
    var documentData = $scope.documentData = {
    "id":rawData[i]["id"],
    "organizationNameGE":rawData[i]["organizationNameGE"],
    "organizationNameEN":rawData[i]["organizationNameEN"],
    "cardNumber":rawData[i]["cardNumber"]
    };

camForm.on('form-loaded', function() {

      camForm.variableManager.createVariable({
        name: 'documentData',
        type: 'json',
        value: documentData
      });

    });
```

but it throws exception that i have Unexpected end of input, but when i replace file data with custom data it works perfectly , what am i missing here?
how can i manage to generate one form for each json data object at a time?
Also  i  have tried  this:
I have added TaskListener in user  task process   in java  it looks  like this

```
public class FormListener implements TaskListener {
    public void notify(DelegateTask arg0) {

        long id = (Long) arg0.getVariable("id");
        String organizationNameGE=(String) arg0.getVariable("organizationNameGE");
        String organizationNameEN=(String) arg0.getVariable("organizationNameEM");
        String cardNumber=(String) arg0.getVariable("cardNumber");
        arg0.setVariable("id",id);
        arg0.setVariable("organizationNameGE",organizationNameGE);
        arg0.setVariable("organizationNameEN",organizationNameEN);
        arg0.setVariable("cardNumber",cardNumber);


    }
}
```

and  i  also  have  this  code  inside  my  embeded  form  script:

```
inject(['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    var variableManager = camForm.variableManager;

    // OnFormLoaded
    camForm.on('form-loaded', function() {
      // Fetch Variables
      // - General
      variableManager.fetchVariable('processInitiator'); // set by the engine
      // - Process
      variableManager.fetchVariable('id'); // set in an earlier form
      variableManager.fetchVariable('organizationNameGE');
      variableManager.fetchVariable('organizationNameEN');
      variableManager.fetchVariable('cardNumber');
    });

    // OnVariablesFetched
    camForm.on('variables-fetched', function() {
      // After the variables are fetched, bind the value to the angular scope
      // - General
      $scope.processInitiator = variableManager.variable('processInitiator').value;

      // - Process
      $scope.id = variableManager.variable('id').value;
      $scope.organizationNameGE= variableManager.variable('organizationNameGE').value;
      $scope.organizationNameEN = variableManager.variable('organizationNameEN').value;
      $scope.cardNumber=variableManager.variable('cardNumber').value;

    });
```

but   it  doens;t  gives  me any result  i mean  it  trows  exception like  this 
SPIN/JACKSON-JSON-01004 Unable to find 'id'
what   should  i  change  to  make  my  code   work?

Answer (score 0):

Just create  a execution listner which executed at start of the user task, you can make it in the diagram. In the Listner implementation  read the JSON as key value pair , set the key as camunda variable name and value as well. Now in the form give cam variable as the key that you have given in Listner implementation. You can implement the Listner in JavaScript /Java.

Comment: I have added TaskListener  with  similar  implementation(  i will  type  it  in general question)  but  it  doesn't  works it  trows   exception  like this :SPIN/JACKSON-JSON-01004 Unable to find 'id'